# SEOプラグインにおけるlocationは何を意味するのでしょうか？ What does "location" mean within a SEO plugin

Tags: english-to-japanese

すみません。母語サイトに帰って来てしまいました。

自分のビジネスサイトをSEO強化させる為にSEOプラグインで有名な[Yoast SEO](https://ja.wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-seo/)を使い始めたら元がアメリカ製のプラグインなので日本語化が不十分でいつの間にか英→日翻訳を助けるようになりました。（日本語化率現在56％）。その中で英語でlocationという言葉[image: "Use my current location"とか"Location logo"]にぶち当たってしまったのですが適当な言葉は何でしょう。教えて下さい(m_m)。（個人的にはドメインかと推測しています。）

---

I started using a SEO plug-in, called Yoast SEO, which is a tool to enhance the internal structure inside your or business homepage. Because the plug-in is ( was ) developed by Americans, however very popular, though the language fitness to Japanese is yet 56%, I started helping translation. However, I am not sure how I should translated the word "location", which you can see at the picture, could anyone have any idea what this could mean. ( I personally guessing this could be a "domain" ). Thank you and I know I am at the risk of this being busted.

Comment: Well...it looks like there would be no place for me here in SE who is strong at this very specific topic and Japanese. ( I went to スタック・オーバーフロー but it seems there doesn't "support" applications.......)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about the Japanese language.

Comment: @istrasci Although we might understand what this *location* refers to just by reading the English document, choosing the best translation is not really simple, and he's also explicitly asking for the best Japanese word.

Comment: @naruto:  Yes, but without the correct semantics, it's futile to suggest the best Japanese word.  That's why he should ask the developer what "location" really means.  Once that's figured out, the best Japanese word can be suggested (although he probably won't need our advice).

Comment: @naruto Thank you. First of all, where should I ask or could you let me know "even if it is English", where can I understand what the location means "more precisely"? I personally think this question is on the threshold between off topic and on topic. as I say I "I am at the risk of this being busted". Thank you.

Comment: For all of you, kindly choose to close or not. I think this kind of matter **could** happen. Either way, I will be satisfied. But fundamentally thinking, what is the tag "word choice" up here for???

Comment: I am sorry. I think I chose the tag "word choice", because it is or was so...and if the moderators or whoever changed to the tag "english-to-japanese", wouldn't that mean here **the translation from English to Japanese is O.K**, because, the very tag is, **english-to;japanese**.!

Comment: Kindly go to Meta since I am getting perplexed...thank you for all of this. - -

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yoast SEO の一部として [Local SEO](https://yoast.com/wordpress/plugins/local-seo/) という機能があり、それの翻訳をしているようですね。これは、ビジネスの行われている地域（国・都市）に基づいて検索効率が高まるよう、色々してくれるというもののようです。Googleで「クリーニング店」とか「バッティングセンター」とか「ヨガ教室」とかで検索すると、近くにある実店舗の一覧が地図付きで出てきますよね、その機能に関するSEOをやってくれるプラグインです。煎じ詰めると[この仕組み](https://www.suzukikenichi.com/blog/google-recommends-using-schema-org-for-location-pages/)が関係しています。

ということで、locationは、ネット上のURLとかドメインのことではなく、地理的な「場所」「位置」のことだと思います。

[ヘルプ](https://kb.yoast.com/kb/configuration-guide-for-local-seo/)を見る限り、locationとは「ビジネス名（店舗名）」とか「住所」とか「電話番号」とかを含む登録項目のようであり、複数のlocationを管理できるようです。つまりlocationとは、具体的には個々の支店とか営業所とか事務所とかのことを指しています。複数の支店を登録させているような文脈で、「位置を追加して住所を登録する」とか「場所の削除」とか言われると逆に分かりづらい気がします。ですので個人的には思い切って「**ロケーション**」で統一してしまうのがわかりやすいのでは、と思います。漢字がいいなら「**場所情報**」でもいいかもしれません。

一般的に、ソフト自体の機能に習熟しないままに逐語訳させられると、どんなに語学力がある人でもミスをしてしまいます。まずはそのプラグインのヘルプを読み込み、実際に使い込んで、「location」がどんな場面で使われているのか理解してから訳すべきだと思います。

Comment: Thank you for your help!. By the way, will you join. SEO people know about Yoast but why do they leaven it abandoned......